# what is props in redux how the methods are getting attached to it

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am following udemy tutorial for burger builder in react redux

```
           <div>
            <Burger ingredients={this.props.ings} />
            <BuildControls
                ingredientAdded={this.props.onIngredientAdded}
                ingredientRemoved={this.props.onIngredientRemoved}
                disabled={disabledInfo}
                purchasable={this.updatePurchaseState(this.props.ings)}
                ordered={this.purchaseHandler}
                price={this.props.price} />
             </div>
```

The  following is my mapDispatchToProps where i am dispatching to  reducer

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onIngredientAdded: (ingName) => dispatch(actions.addIngredient(ingName)),
        onIngredientRemoved: (ingName) => dispatch(actions.removeIngredient(ingName)),
        onInitIngredients: () => dispatch(actions.initIngredients()),
        onInitPurchase : () => dispatch(actions.PurchaseInit())
    }
}
```

1) But i am  confused , how we are calling  onIngredientAdded and 
   onIngredientRemoved  as props

2) I have a mapstateToProps which map my state ,to props so i can
   call all my state proprties as props but i didn't add any  of these
   methods there how can i call my local methods as props

3) Did i miss any topic plese help me

Comment: This isn't redux directly, this is a package called react-redux. It exposes something called connect() that is used to connect functions traditionally named mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps to the component. connect() is a higher-order component (HOC) that takes those functions and gets values from redux to then render the component by passing the results in as props.

Comment: got it thanks 

But out of my curiosity if connect does the trick  why again we have to pass the state varables in mapSatetoprosp

Comment: You should look up the react-redux documentation for more.

Comment: @lostcoder you have to pass the state, which you really need for the specific component, i.e. selective to pass the state segment to the component, not the entire state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @person27 mentioned, there is no replacement for [reading the documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch). What I think you're confused by is using 2 methods to map data to the props.

`mapStateToProps` creates props out of **pieces of data stored in your state**.  These are static (but possibly changing) values you need to use in your component. These values generally line up to variables (numbers, arrays, objects, etc.).

`mapDispatchToProps` creates props out of **functional actions** that are executed with the **dispatch** function to make new changes to that state. These are used to create functions that your component will call.

The Redux store contains **all of the data for your entire application**, so the purpose of using these methods is to **specify exactly what pieces of data/actions** your particular component will be making use of. Using `connect` on a component will not do anything if the state data and actions are not specified in these functions, as by default it does not actually connect any data at all.

Your Redux store is like a big menu of all the actions and state data in your application, and you're using these methods to order only the specific ingredients you want on your burger (component).

Hope this helps, I found it a bit confusing myself at first.